# angular http update without calling subscribe

Tags: angular

I have this method in my http service:

```
update(field: Field) {
    return this.http.put<Field>(`${environment.apiUrl}/fields`, field).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            this.toastr.success(response.message);
            return response.model;
        }),
    );
}
```

It seems that in order to invoke this from a component, I have to subscribe to it like this:

```
this.fieldService.update(currentField).subscribe(field => console.log(field));
```

I would prefer it if I could invoke it like this:

```
this.fieldService.update(currentField);
```

As a bonus, I would like to be able to both.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would prefer it if I could invoke it like this:
>
> ```
> this.fieldService.update(currentField);
> ```

Then call subscribe() from within the service. But this is a terrible idea, because you generally want to be able to know if the update succeeded or not, and when it has succeeded, in order to chain some other operation, like for example navigating to the page displaying the value that you just updated.

> As a bonus, I would like to be able to both. Is this possible?

No, unless you define two different methods, or unless you pass sme argument to the method telling it to subscribe or not.

Comment: I guess I will live with it then :)

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, I assume you are trying to implement a generic toaster for REST requests. If so, you may be happier changing the way to do it.

I *personally* would implement a service for that, one that you would be able to call whenever and from wherever you want, respecting your application's module hyerarchy, of course.